# Command-line to get this system information

Tags: 14.04, command-line, system-info

When I log in to my digital ocean image, I see this information appearing.

> Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-57-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
>   System information as of Sat Nov 28 11:16:20 SGT 2015
>
>   System load:  0.09               Processes:           74   Usage of
>     /:   11.7% of 19.56GB   Users logged in:     0   Memory usage: 39%
>     IP address for eth0: XX.XX.XX.XX   Swap usage:   0%
>
>   Graph this data and manage this system at:
>     https://landscape.canonical.com/

Which command-line, if any, should I use to make this information appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual messages displayed are stored in `/etc/update-motd.d`, where motd means `message-of-the-day`.

If we're looking at getting that information separately, there's several commands you can employ. The rest - just parsing those commands into pretty output with `awk` or even `tr`

- `lsb_release -a` will tell you the type and version of system you have
- `df -h /dev/sda1` will tell you usage for your disk. `/dev/sda1` can be changed to whatever partition your Ubuntu is on.
- `ip addr show eth0` or `ifconfig eth0` will show you the IP address
- `uptime` will tell you number of users logged in and load average
- `free` will tell you swap and overall memory usage